# Deprecated warning on textTheme flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter 2.5.
I wrote following code which gives me deprecated warning in `**textTheme**` property.

```
return MaterialApp(
      // home: homePage(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme
        )
      ),
      darkTheme:
          ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: MyRoutes.homeRoutes,
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => LoginPage(),
        MyRoutes.homeRoutes: (context) => homePage(),
        MyRoutes.loginRoutes: (context) => LoginPage(),
      },
    );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some properties of TextTheme were deprecated and changed for another name in Flutter 1.13.8. Maybe you are using old text style properties:

You can find a list of the new properties [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/2-2-deprecations#texttheme)